# Using Microsoft.AspNetCore.All package in netstandard

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-standard

At the moment I'm porting an asp web api to .Net Core.

The api uses a Class library which provides some implementations of the ActionFilterAttribute class.

So I have to port this class library as well.
When I tried to add the nuget package Microsoft.AspNetCore.All to the class library I recived this error:

> Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.0.0 is not compatible with
>   netstandard2.0

When I change the target framework to netcoreapp2.0, I'm able to install the package, but of course I need an entry point for this target type.

How can I create a netcore class library which can use the Microsoft.AspNetCore.All package

Greetings

Answer (score 10):

The metapackage [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.All`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All) is only available for .NETCoreApp. This is [by design](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/243) since its explictly targeted as a convenience package for web applications running on .NET Core. In order to work its magic at publishing time (stripping of unused dependencies), it requires the .NET Core runtime store which is only available for .NET Core itself.

All other projects, including library projects running on .NET Standard but also including all projects that run on the full .NET Framework, should use individual package references instead.

So instead of referencing `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All`, you would be referencing e.g. [`Microsoft.AspNetCore`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore), or [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc) to get your `ActionFilterAttribute`.

Comment: Microsoft.AspNetCore or Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc latest version is .net core 2.2 (.net standard 2.0)  How it's possible to override for example ActionMethodSelectorAttribute in class library?

Answer (score 7):

You can't (well technically you could via NuGet Fallback, but you shouldn't as it may affect your portability) and you shouldn't.

The `.All` package is a convenience meta-package, so you don't need to reference a dozen or other assemblies for even the simplest ASP.NET Core Project.

It's targeting .NET Core for a reason, so you can't use it in .NET Standard.

When you publish your application, the unused packages will be stripped off. When doing a class library you don't want dependency on everything but only the packages which are required by your project.